# twisted TCP to IRC

Tags: python, twisted

I'm an struggling to get my twisted IRC bot to echo data send to a TCP server to an IRC channel.

What I have currently done is to have a TCP server append all the messages to a list and then each time the IRC bot's RecievedData function is called it checks to see if there are messages and displays them.

To improve on this I'd like to tell the that news messages are in the queue and it must now display them.

Here is the code so far

Main.py:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5005624

ircbot.py:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dae18fe12792a6a8dd4d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very much like [one of the questions answered in the Twisted FAQ](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#HowdoImakeinputononeconnectionresultinoutputonanother).

Essentially, change your factory so that the `Echo` instance it creates is accessible somehow - as a global, if you like (globals are bad, don't use them) - and then call a method on it when data arrives (instead of calling the `append` method of the `messages` list).